# Answer Count on Stats Page Off

Tags: support, tags, top-users, answer-count

So I've been immensely narcissistic on my march toward a silver tag badge, and I've been checking the stats page incessantly. In my looking, I found that the number of answers that the stats page says I have in a tag does not equal the number of answers that the tag says I have in said tag.

For example, take a look at [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95589) and note that for the `sql` tag, I have 153 answers. If you were to click it, you'd see that the 153 number is correct, as far as [the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:95589+sql) is concerned. But, [the stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=sql&sort=stats) shows only 129. I should note that I've never asked a question on SO, so all posts are answers.

Buh-wha?

Comment: Beware! It's all just a ploy to increase the profile count for a bigger bubble!

Comment: @random: I have no idea what you're talking about. Wink wink nudge nudge knowwhatimean saynomore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag stats page only counts non-community wiki posts with at least one upvote. This search will show that you only have <strike>129</strike> 157 answers tagged <kbd>sql</kbd> with at least 1 upvote:

```
user:95589 votes:1 [sql]
```

Comment: Aha, that be it. I can't believe I have 24 answers with 0 upvotes. That's deflating my balloon quite a bit!

Comment: Also, feel free to add a `status-moron` tag to this, since I can't.

Comment: @Eric: I don't see why you would know that the posts have to have one upvote - it's certainly not well documented. However, I have retagged to `support` instead of `bug`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is printed right at the bottom of every tag stats page:

**Only non community-wiki questions and answers are included in these totals**

Comment: I know that this is the official answer and all, but I only have 1 CW SQL answer. Kyle's explanation is much more accurate in terms of the numbers.

Comment: I checked that first Jeff (using wiki:1) but he only had 1 wiki question.