# Wrong Answer Count on Stats Page

Tags: support, top-users, answer-count

According to the message printed at the bottom of the stats page (and as confirmed by Jeff's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18945/answer-count-on-stats-page-off/19007#19007) to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18945/answer-count-on-stats-page-off/)):

> Only non community-wiki questions and
>   answers are included in these totals

However, if I look at the [stats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=weblogic&sort=stats&pagesize=50) of the weblogic tag (for example), it says I answered **2** questions in the last 30 days (and I don't even appear in the all time stats). But the following search [`user:70604 [weblogic]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A70604+[weblogic]) shows that I answered 14 questions (and 13 in the Last 30 days at the time of writing this).

IMHO, there must be a bug somewhere.

I've checked for questions mentioning the same issue but I couldn't find something really describing this behavior as a bug (and the [Bug(?): incorrect answer count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8058/bug-incorrect-answer-count) question and answer don't apply in my case).

Comment: For the time being, the documentation would be here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25507/where-the-numbers-have-no-fame/25509#25509

Comment: I was afraid of this: the total number of answers provided is... not the total number of answers provided. -_-'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're checking out the weblogic stats page, and you're comparing against the search, [run it against **[`weblogic`]**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A70604+%5Bweblogic%5D) instead of **[`sql`]**.

The results show 12 answers by you, but only two (2) of those with a vote each.

It is these two with upvotes that are counted on your stats leaderboard appearance.

[image: tongue you very much]

#### Number of answers provided

Even though you have thrown up over a dozen answers, the only ones worth counting as part of "**number of answers provided**" are those that have been upvoted and are non-wiki. Accepted does not count in this metric.

As for documentation, [it's here now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25507/wrong-answer-count-on-stats-page/25509#25509).

Comment: Thanks, there was a little typo in my question. Nevertheless, please tell me **where do you see that only answers with at least 1 vote are counted**? This may be the actual behavior but, as I wrote, this is not the expected one (read the first sentence of my question again).

Comment: Why do you show me the total score? I'm obviously not expecting the total score to include answers with 0 votes... I'm of course talking about the 2nd column i.e. the **number of answers provided**. As the legend states, why wouldn't all answers be included in this count? What is the rationale behind counting only upvoted answer? This is not logical. BTW, I don't think the link at the bottom of your answer is correct (or I don't get it).

Comment: Clarified as to what the **Number of answers provided** actually means.

Comment: Where is this documented? That's not my understanding of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18945/answer-count-on-stats-page-off/19007#19007