# The top users page and profile tag list: one or both seems wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-users

As has been well-documented already ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18945/answer-count-on-stats-page-off) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25507/wrong-answer-count-on-stats-page), for example), the top users page for a tag will usually show *fewer* total answers than you've actually given for that tag since it doesn't count answers that are Community Wiki or which don't have any upvotes.

However, I've noticed over the past few weeks that I've been consistently credited with *more* answers than I should for the `matlab` tag. I'll show you what I mean using the traditional form of communication for our people: screen shots embellished with free-hand drawings...

[**Top users page:**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/matlab/topusers)

[image]

[**My profile page tag list:**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52738/gnovice)

[image]

**EDIT:**

After digging a little deeper, it seem that **both** numbers above may be wrong according to the following searches:

- Searched `user:52738 wiki:0 votes:1 [matlab]` and got 192 hits (instead of 190).
- Searched `user:52738 [matlab]` and got 216 hits (instead of 188).

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Sometimes the tag counts are off.  I'd guess that's what the problem is.

Comment: @jjnguy: You may be right. I just double-checked by searching `user:52738 [matlab]` and I got 216 results, 28 more than my tag list says!

Comment: Repwhoring by painting - I cannot support this! (+1)

Comment: @John: It's not Rep-whoring, it's Rep-defending. If I *didn't* add nice painty pictures I'd be downvoted. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is no longer an issue, we now present total scores per tag on the user page.

(will be deployed today) 
[image]

**Too tricky** ... the stats page is now regenerated once a day, so it will not be exactly in sync with the tags on the user page, which is generated on demand.

- We could use the cached values on the user page, but that will raise other issues
- We can not move back to generating the stats page on demand due to performance.

I think the best resolution I can offer is putting a note at the bottom of the page that says: "the results on this page are regenerated daily and may be up to 1 day old"

Comment: Yeah, I recently noticed that the stats page only appeared to be updating once a day, but wouldn't that mean it should potentially have a *lower* count of questions answered in that tag? Currently, the tag stats has me at 587, but my user profile says 555! I still stand by my assertion that something isn't right, and I don't think it's status-by-design.

Comment: @gnostradamus, Ill have a look next week ...

Comment: This is excellent! But is it working right? Look at [Jeff's profile page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) -- he has a bronze `[chat]` badge, but it shows only 94 total score.

Comment: @Jon: I believe the total score is the total upvotes *minus* the total downvotes. The badges are awarded based on total upvotes only, so Jeff must have a few downvotes bringing the total score down.

Comment: Everything looks good now! The numbers are finally making sense. And it only took 6 to 8 weeks (times 7) to fix! ;)