# Profile Page and Top Users Page doesn't match?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, badges

Similar to this question, except this one claims it's fixed: [The top users page and profile tag list: one or both seems wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29919/the-top-users-page-and-profile-tag-list-one-or-both-seems-wrong)

My profile page claims I have a tag where I answered 56 non-wiki questions, with a total score of 105.

The "Top Users" page for this tag says I have 99 points and 50 answers.

### Profile Page

[image]

### Top Users Page

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are not updated at the same time (different parts of the sites are updated at different times). Look again later (or tomorrow) and the result will be more recent (but could still be different).